# How to join tables resulting in JSON with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, join

Having the following entities, Rent and Region:

```
class Rent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region

  validates :region, presence: true
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rents
end
```

To get a Rent object is simple doing the following:

```
  def show
    rent = Rent.find(params[:id])
    render json: rent
  end
```

This will successfully return the Rent:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "blah",
  "region_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.407Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.407Z"
}
```

Now, I want to join this result with the Region. The *ideal result* would be similar to this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "blah",
  "region_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.407Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.407Z"
  "region": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "blah",
    "created_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.507Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-12-16T04:09:00.507Z"
  }
}
```

In order to accomplish this, the official [RoR documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) mention the use of the `join` clause which should solve this issue. So this is what I did:

```
  def show
    rent = Rent.joins(:region).find(params[:id])
    render json: rent
  end
```

Unfortunately the result of this last snipe is exactly the same that getting the rent by it self. There is not `region` object included on the JSON response.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
rent = Rent.find(params[:id])
render :json => rent.to_json(:include => :region)
```

This will include the object data from the relationship when it is creating the JSON for your object.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Please, tell me a bit more about it, how does it work and any link to ror documentation :)

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json the official docs are here, showing the options you can use including this one. Also check out this blog http://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods

Comment: Other things you might find useful are "only" to show only the data fields that you need in the JSON and "methods" so that you can include the output of a method that you have on the model